# Why have an executable between the binding and the datacontrol instead of directly connection between the two?

Tags: oracle-adf

In ADF why do we require to have an executable between the bindings and the datacontrol. Let say I have a hierarchical datamodel which is exposed by the datacontrol(DC). Why can't we have a hierarchical binding directly to the DC instead of going through an extra layer called `executable`?

Answer (score 0):

executable contains the declarations for iterators, variables, etc and bindings refers to those declarations in more than one binding. This is the modularization designed by Oracle. Just a design approach.